# Why is an application running as administrator unable to see some registry keys?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm writing a small program to help me save and load custom EQ presets after updating to a new build of Windows 10 wipes them out.  I've found out where they're stored in the Registry, but when I try to access that key programmatically, it's as if it doesn't exist.  You can see the "Render" sub-key in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of Registry showing "Render" sub-key.]

I used the following lines of code to try to access the sub-key:

```
var hive = Registry.LocalMachine;
var keys = hive.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
    ?.OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
    ?.OpenSubKey("Windows")
    ?.OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
    ?.OpenSubKey("MMDevices")
    ?.OpenSubKey("Audio")?.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Here you can see that the sub-key doesn't seem to exist.

[image: Screenshot showing sub-keys visible to my program.]

My application is configured to run as Administrator so it should have full access to the Registry.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you're running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine and are therefore subject to registry redirection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is probably right. Use Sysinternals ProcMon to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Damien_The_Unbeliever was correct.  Once I configured my project to target x64 I was able to see all four sub-keys.

Comment: Never target x64, AnyCPU + Prefer 32-bit unchecked is plenty good enough.  That way it still works correctly on an old machine with a 32-bit OS.